# SSRS 2008 sub total and Grand total not adding up correct

Tags: reporting-services

i am new in this forum and newbie  on  SSRS 2008, have created report ,3 level of total ,

1 level total by asset by   expression  used by  Max(Fields!ACQUISITIONPRICE.Value)

2 level by  Fixed asset by group expression =Sum(Fields!ACQUISITIONPRICE.Value) this not adding correct either, because the ASSET ID total I used as Max so its not giving me correct me correct total

3 level is Grand total all the asset ,  this total is not coming correct , its adding up all acuistion price in column was hidden , I just want to add only what's in the total by asset id

can any one please help me with this, I have been working on this for while, have not figure this out yet,

I really need help, thanks in advance

Comment: would like to reopen this issue, its not resolve, new to this form,

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`=Sum(Max(Fields!ACQUISITIONPRICE.Value,"NameOfGroupHere"))`

Where "NameOfGroupHere" is the name of the innermost group defined in your table.

Comment: thanks JC for quick reply,  I did add the sum to 2 level total

Comment: my =Sum(Max(Fields!ACQUISITIONPRICE.Value,"ASSETGROUP"))2 level total by  Assetgroup so I changed that by

Comment: it did not give me correct total either , I have group by assetgroup

Comment: Don't put a field name in there. I'm talking about the name of the group.

Comment: JC seems like asking a lot, I donot understand, where I can find the nameofgroup  can you please direct me right direction, I will be grateful, I donot much about SSRS, I am starting to learn , is there a way to post my query , thanks again

Comment: You have group levels defined in the report. They show up at the bottom of the window when you have the table selected. Each of those groupings has a name, whether you set it manually or leave it at the SSRS default. Use the name of the group as the second parameter to Max() or any other aggregate function to specify the domain to which the aggregate should apply.

Comment: in Row groups I have 3 groups >  Assetsgroups, 2 Name, 3 Assetid,

Comment: that's means i need  to create new dataset for parameter, this is  new to me, can you please direct me right direction, i am searching it on the internet also, can you please help, what the next step

Comment: JC  i changed my Asset id expression changed from Max to first, because when i was using sum on Max it was picking the highest amount of the asset and adding that to the group level, i think i have figue it out innermost group is Assetgroup so i change the expression for group level and some group total come out correct,but some of the asset group totol did not add up correct, donot know the reason, =Sum(Fields!AUISITIONPRICE.Value,"ASSETGROUP")

Comment: with same expression one group total is correct but other group total is not correct, what i did wrong, can you please help, and how can i do my Grand total for Acquistion price .that's not coming correct either, rest of the report is ok,

Comment: JC I am trying different approach on same report on Acquistion price

Comment: column price showing for each row, is there any way I can change my query price can show only one time, I did change to

Comment: SUM(DISTINCT(ACQUISITIONPRICE)) AS ACQUISITIONPRICE  I thought this will do the trick and it help me with totals also, seems like it did not work,it still showing price for each line, for example------- Name   AssetID   Acquistionprice  Depr Amount---------Computer  1111    $1000.00         $200.00-----

Comment: can you please help me what can I do make acquisition price to show only once that will be helpful,